# Could not write the disk image (/media/hack_den/Alpha_0419/data/distro/tuxlinux-x86-dist.iso) to the device (/dev/sdd)

Tags: live-usb, startup-disk-creator

I am trying to create bootable-disk of Tux Linux through startup disk creator.
However, I am getting this error (also given in title)
[image: screenshot]

What can I do? Please help

Comment: Did you look for clues in system logs?  (`dmesg` is where I'd look first, `journalctl` likely second.. but I'd expect clues from `dmesg`)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what happened, but using sudo solved the problem. Since no tutorial uses sudo, I assume it is my python path mess.... and using sudo used a different path or binary

Comment: In my case it was a bad connection in the desktop's cheapo front USB ports. It kept failing (after several minutes) repeatedly, until I plugged the drive into the back.

Comment: try to eject, re-inserting

Comment: Encountered the same error today, fixed by unmounting the USB's partition in gparted.

Answer (score 16):

@manolius’s suggestion worked for me. Add `sudo` to the command:

```
sudo usb-creator-gtk
```

This is because USB Creator needs to:

- Install a boot loader
- Format a device
- Image a device
- Mount a device

Most of these actions require `root`, as block devices are owned by `root`.

Comment: You would THINK that Canonical would point this out in their "create a USB startup disk" instructions... Or that the GUI would request root to do the work... But Nooooo! This is the first place I could find the name of the application to run from the command line...

Comment: In case of Lubuntu, it is `usb-creator-kde`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of suggestions above did not work for my case.
My solution was simple: I just re-plugged into another USB slot and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when I'm reading the image through the network.

I'm able to burn this USB with my regular user as soon as the image file is local.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to create a disk image with Startup Disk Creator and I get the same error:

```
Could not write the disk image (/home/user/Downloads/ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso) to the device (/dev/sdd).
```

So I just tried it with Disks, which is generally preinstalled, and it worked!

Just

- select your device on the left
- in the selection click 'Restore Disk Image...'
- select the right image
- then Start Creating

That's it!

***-RD***